# best practice to create app id and app secret for an api

Tags: api, security, software-design

I want to learn best practices to create unique app id and app secret for api authantication. Right now I'm just creating appid by UUID generators and creating hash(md5) with random texts for app secret. But it looks like not secure especially for app secret. 
So it would be nice to hear other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the app_id is public. It is not kept secret. UUID, email address, uuid, or an integer should suffice.

For the app secret, any quality PRNG will suffice. The MD5/hashing of random data will simply give you another random token.

Your operating system is the best source for random numbers. Every language has a different API to get at it.

The feasibility of cracking the secret is a function of the length of the key. A 256 bit key is considered uncrackable under the right conditions.

For python, this is the code to get the secret:

```
import os
import base64

key_bytes = os.urandom(256)
# If you need to pass it in a URL, you could base64 it,
# or convert it to hex
key_b64 = base64.b64encode(key_bytes)
key_hex = ''.join( [hex(x) for x in key_bytes])

print 'b64', key_b64
print 'hex', key_hex
```

outputs:

```
b64 ypPp16psb1mBrlS5BE01kcwB+tjwOdDbu3K2Ix0cYz5KxCX42PoRR5a2cpwZGhULeW5BEFenwg5G55m8czU+gF8yS5wz7BfCaT8Z15pgarUM+rrPl/tbYKu3Hc0FE8/5jczZKwFlV37Etq/Hn2gT/9njXn1YIh+NlLBec6Yp3Y6dbSD6zqHv60qPZSUqmVRL9UrbJBAa38gCgMjqj79Qe/pMBpH7tMAKrLelmOBedklme9kZzAJrEpFwtp65K8h3RLSDXx0qVNjrToJquaDFOKytwlwkYtV3ANQ/bxLgEN8zXfGalXsO/6d/ZDi03Kjlj36rSL2fcCG0w5oiYTitMQ==
hex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
```